# Run SVM on IRIS DataSet and get ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, dataset

Who can explain this in a simple way to me?
I include the full code for your convenience.

I have this code which loads IRIS dataset and runs SVM:

```
from sklearn import svm
import pandas as pd


def prepare_iris_DS():
    print("Loading iris DS...")
    url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data'
    iris = pd.read_csv(url, names=["sepal length", "sepal width", "petal length", "petal width", "Species"])
    df = pd.DataFrame(iris, columns=["sepal length", "sepal width", "petal length", "petal width", "Species"])

    df.head()
    iris.head()

    print("Iris DS is Loaded")

    columns, labels = ["sepal length", "sepal width"], ["Iris-setosa", "Iris-virginica"]

    total = df.shape[0]
    df = df[df.Species.isin(labels)]
    X = df[columns]

    print("selected {0} entries out of {1} from the dataset based on labels {2}".format(len(X), total, str(labels)))

    Y = df[["Species"]]
    Y.loc[Y.Species != labels[0], 'Species'] = 0.0
    Y.loc[Y.Species == labels[0], 'Species'] = 1.0

    X = X.as_matrix()
    Y = Y.as_matrix()

    return X, Y


X, Y = prepare_iris_DS()

rbf_svc = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.1, C=0.1)
rbf_svc.fit(X, Y)
```

I keep getting error on the very last line : rbf_svc.fit(X, Y)

```
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 172, in check_classification_targets

raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'
```

But ... 
When i put this command it simply WORKED.
I don't understand why? i appreciate a clear / simple answer

```
Y = Y.as_matrix().astype(float)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When: `Y = Y.as_matrix()`, observe the data type of the target array:

```
>>> Y.dtype
object
```

The `fit` method of `SVC` expects an array iterable of numerical values as it's training vector, *X*. But currently, you've passed an array of numerical string values to it which is incorrect.

This arises due to the fact that *Y* inherits the `dtypes` of `df[['Species]]` when assigned to it directly. So, even though you have performed boolean indexing and got rid of the string values by replacing them with boolean values *(0/1)* during `loc` operation, the dtype of *Y* is unaffected and remains of `object` type.

Hence, the need to typecast them back to `int/float` dtype which could then be understood by the `fit` function.

```
Y = Y.as_matrix().astype(float).ravel()  # ravel to flatten the 2D array to 1D
```

Now, when you test:

```
>>> Y.dtype
float64
```

Also, you can include the following changes:

```
X = df[columns].copy()
Y = df[["Species"]].copy()
```

to avoid the `SettingWithCopyWarning` warnings by creating a deep copy of the dataframe instead of just assigning it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.
but why i didn't need to do astype(float) when taking a matrix for the X?
here i mean:
       X = X.as_matrix()

Comment: You weren't required to perform any typecasting for *X*  simply because the subset of `DF` you allocated for *X* already contained floats in them - namely(*sepal length, sepal width, petal length, petal width*) were all of dtype `float64`. But the *species* column wasn't. Hence, the need to make only *Y* as numeric type.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was helpful !